# Django ORM QuerySet Takes Too Much Time in Docker

Tags: django, docker

I have a simple query in my django.

```
values = ['profile_url', 'name','profit']
home = Home.objects.get(homename='Valley Homes')
user_filters = {"name":"san agustin", "age":21}
user_excludes = {}
users = (User.objects.annotate(distinct_user=ArrayAgg(*values, distinct=True)).filter(home=home, **user_filters).select_related(*user_filters.keys()).exclude(**user_excludes).values(*values))
```

On local ec2 instance it takes up to 4 seconds to query

On docker it takes up to 84 seconds which is horrible.

I thought using `select_related` would shorten time but still it doesnt.

Really need help in improving performance on docker. How can i make it faster like in local?

I checked memory and CPU it doesnt seem to be the problem, it spikes up to 13% during the query but quickly goes back to 1% after that.

Comment: Have you tried fetch_related? can you also check your memory usage in docker?